# How do I assign a global initialized event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got this code in my App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.TextChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_TextChangedEvent));
}
private void TextBox_TextChangedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Works
}
```

I would like to do something similar for the InitializedEvent.
Here's my failed attempt:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.InitializedEvent, new EventHandler(FrameworkElement_InitializedEvent));
}
private void FrameworkElement_InitializedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Is the InitializedEvent somewhere else?
Is this even possible?

I've tried using the LoadedEvent:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(FrameworkElement_LoadedEvent));
}
private void FrameworkElement_LoadedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Fires only for Windows
}
```

It only fired for Windows and not the controls inside the Windows. I did realize though; that when I added a loaded event to a Label that I had inside my Window; the global `FrameworkElement_LoadedEvent` fired for that Label even though my normal loaded event *(That I made for the Label specifically)* was empty. I've also tried these:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), Button.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Button_LoadedEvent));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Grid), Grid.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Grid_LoadedEvent));
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGrid), DataGrid.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(DataGrid_LoadedEvent));
```

But they don't fire unless I add another empty loaded event on those controls specifically.

My goal is to build up a sort of a time log of every control that becomes initialized.

How can I achieve this without adding loaded events on every single control I have?

(I have a lot)

Comment: Event Manager is for handling Routed Events. I don't think Initialized is a routed event (in other words, when raised it does not bubble/tunnel through the controls).

Comment: Maybe you could tell us _why_ do you need such a global event handler?

Comment: @dymanoid I want to build up a sort of a time log of every control that becomes initialized.

Comment: I've tried using the Loaded event, but that only works for... sort of container controls and not the controls inside the container controls.

Comment: @JeffR. Is there an alternative to what I'm trying? Perhaps another type of event that will fire for all my controls? Including Grids, Buttons and Labels and such?

Comment: Using Initialized is fine but it just can't be a single global assignment like that. You would need to subscribe to the event for each control you have. Usually the parent control does not raise Initialized though until all its children are initialized. So it is probably safe to assume if the root panel or even the Window raises Initialized then all the children are too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you are!

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Constructor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region Constructor

    static App()
    {
        // set MyInitialized=true for new windows (happens before Loaded)
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), FrameworkElement.SizeChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnSizeChanged));

        // our loaded handler
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded), true);
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ContentElement), FrameworkContentElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded), true);
    }

    private static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("SizeChanged {0}", sender);
        SetMyInitialized((Window) sender, true);
    }

    private static void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O}: {sender} loaded");
    }

    #endregion

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // MyInitialized
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region MyInitialized

    public static void SetMyInitialized(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(MyInitializedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetMyInitialized(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(MyInitializedProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyInitializedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyInitialized", typeof (bool), typeof (App), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnMyInitializedChanged));

    private static void OnMyInitializedChanged(DependencyObject dpo, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs ev)
    {
        if ((bool)ev.NewValue)
        {
            // registering instance handler unbreaks class handlers
            if (dpo is FrameworkElement element)
                element.Loaded += _EmptyRoutedEventHandler;
            if (dpo is FrameworkContentElement contentElement)
                contentElement.Loaded += _EmptyRoutedEventHandler;
        } else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set to false", ev.Property.Name);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("MyInitialized {0} {1}=>{2}", dpo, ev.OldValue, ev.NewValue);
    }

    private static readonly RoutedEventHandler _EmptyRoutedEventHandler = delegate { };

    #endregion              
}
```

---

#### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}">
        <Grid>
            <Border Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="20">
                <TextBlock Background="Orange" Text="hello"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Sample `Console` output:

```
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6052225+02:00: WpfApp3.MainWindow loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6112064+02:00: System.Windows.Controls.Border loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6132008+02:00: System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6141984+02:00: System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6141984+02:00: System.Windows.Controls.Grid loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6151966+02:00: System.Windows.Controls.Border loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6161935+02:00: System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock loaded
2018-07-31T14:20:52.6161935+02:00: System.Windows.Documents.AdornerLayer loaded
```

Comment: :) This works. I did have to comment this part out though:

throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set to false", ev.Property.Name);